# How can I reduce SQL statements using consecutive/chained prefetch_related()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-models

Please let me ask how I can reduce the number of SQL using chained prefetch_related().

I wrote

```
item = Item.objects.prefetch_related('item_photo', 'item_stock', 'item_review',) # .prefetch_related('item_photo').prefetch_related('item_stock')...

item
(0.000) SELECT "item"."id", "item"."name", "item"."price", "item"."category_id", "item"."runs", "item"."wins", "item"."description", "item"."total_sales", "item"."created_at", "item"."updated_at", "item"."on_sale", "item"."note" FROM "item" LIMIT 21; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_photo"."id", "item_photo"."item_id", "item_photo"."photo", "item_photo"."priority", "item_photo"."note" FROM "item_photo" WHERE "item_photo"."item_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) ORDER BY "item_photo"."priority" ASC; args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_stock"."id", "item_stock"."item_id", "item_stock"."stock", "item_stock"."note" FROM "item_stock" WHERE "item_stock"."item_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_review"."id", "item_review"."item_id", "item_review"."user_id", "item_review"."stars", "item_review"."comment", "item_review"."note" FROM "item_review" WHERE "item_review"."item_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); alias=default
<QuerySet [<Item: Apple>, <Item: Banana>, <Item: Orange>, <Item: Lemon>, <Item: Tea>, <Item: Ginger>, <Item: Onion>, <Item: Banana>, <Item: Water>]>
```

but, it displayed many SQL statements even if I bound tables with prefetch_related().

In addition, if I wrote following this in views.py,

```
pk= 4
item = Item.objects.prefetch_related('item_photo', 'item_stock', 'item_review',).get(pk=pk)
context = {
    'form': form,
    'item': item,
    'photos': item.item_photo.values(),
    'stock': item.item_stock.values(),
    'review': item.item_review.values(),
}
```

more SQL were executed.

Even though I modified code using Prefetch(),

```
item = Item.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'item_photo',
        queryset=ItemPhoto.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='ipr',
    ),
    Prefetch(
        'item_stock',
        queryset=ItemStock.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='isr',
    ),
    Prefetch(
        'item_review',
        queryset=ItemReview.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='irr',
    ),
)

item
<QuerySet [<Item: Apple>, <Item: Banana>, <Item: Orange>, <Item: Lemon>, <Item: Tea>, <Item: Ginger>, <Item: Onion>, <Item: Banana>, <Item: Water>]>

item.get(pk=4).ipr[0].photo  # [i.ipr[0].photo for i in item.filter(pk=4)][0]
(0.000) SELECT "item"."id", "item"."name", "item"."price", "item"."category_id", "item"."runs", "item"."wins", "item"."description", "item"."total_sales", "item"."created_at", "item"."updated_at", "item"."on_sale", "item"."note" FROM "item" WHERE "item"."id" = 4 LIMIT 21; args=(4,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_photo"."id", "item_photo"."item_id", "item_photo"."photo", "item_photo"."priority", "item_photo"."note" FROM "item_photo" WHERE "item_photo"."item_id" IN (4) ORDER BY "item_photo"."priority" ASC; args=(4,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_stock"."id", "item_stock"."item_id", "item_stock"."stock", "item_stock"."note" FROM "item_stock" WHERE "item_stock"."item_id" IN (4); args=(4,); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "item_review"."id", "item_review"."item_id", "item_review"."user_id", "item_review"."stars", "item_review"."comment", "item_review"."note" FROM "item_review" WHERE "item_review"."item_id" IN (4); args=(4,); alias=default
Out[74]: <ImageFieldFile: shopping/Lemon/4cfd8e29320d4b63b77f494a759dadf6.jpg>
```

Still, so many SQL were executed.

If so, it seems it is better to write a code like following this because the number of executed SQL is fewer than the above way.

context = {
'form': form,
'item': Item.objects.get(pk=pk),
'photos': ItemPhoto.objects.filter(item_id=pk),
'stock':  ItemStock.objects.get(item_id=pk),
'review':  ItemReview.objects.filter(item_id=pk),
}

In this case, what and how should I change my code to reduce the number of executed SQL if I bind database tables with prefetch_related()?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

◆ models.py（omitted）

```
class Item(models.Model): # Product
    name = models.CharField("商品名", max_length=255, blank=False, default="")
    price = models.DecimalField("価格",
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00, 
        blank=False,
    ) 
    on_sale = models.BooleanField("販売中", default=True)


class ItemStock(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, related_name="item_stock", verbose_name="商品番号")
    stock = models.IntegerField("在庫数", blank=False, default=0)


class ItemPhoto(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="item_photo", verbose_name="商品番号",)
    photo = models.ImageField("商品画像", blank=True, 
        upload_to=get_itemimage_path)


class ItemReview(models.Model):
    STARS_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "★☆☆☆☆"),
        ("2", "★★☆☆☆"),
        ("3", "★★★☆☆"),
        ('4', '★★★★☆'),
        ('5', '★★★★★'),
    )

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name="商品番号",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_review",)
    stars = models.CharField("評価", max_length=1, # evaluation
        choices=STARS_CHOICES, blank=False,
    )
```

Python: 3.9 / Django: 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems it is better to write a code like following this because the number of executed SQL is fewer than the above way.

Let's count the queries executed:

```
context = {
    'form': form,
    'item': Item.objects.get(pk=pk),  # Query 1
    'photos': ItemPhoto.objects.filter(item_id=pk),  # Query 2
    'stock': ItemStock.objects.get(item_id=pk),  # Query 3
    'review': ItemReview.objects.filter(item_id=pk),  # Query 4
}
```

Then let's look at the prefetch version:

```
item = Item.objects.prefetch_related(
    'item_photo', # Query 1
    'item_stock',  # Query 2
    'item_review',  # Query 3
).get(pk=pk)  # Query 4
```

Both will execute 4 queries, and if you need models from 4 tables, there really isn't any other option than to do 4 queries.

**However,** when using `prefetch_related()`, you should only really use `.all()` on the prefetched attribute, not try to e.g. `.filter()` it, because Django won't "emulate" a queryset method on it.

Comment: Your advice is very useful and helpful. Thank you so much! 
I actually use 6 tables, then I checked SQL queries, it showed 5 queries when I used code like your above one and display the page.
And when I used this code using chained prefetch_related(),  8 queries occurred, maybe because I use {% for %} in the template.

{% for race in G1 %}
 {{ race.g1 }}
{% endfor %}

# same SQL query created twice ->
SELECT "g1"."id", "g1"."item_id", "g1"."g1", "g1"."note" FROM "g1" WHERE "g1"."item_id" = 4;

In this case, should I use the above way not the below, using prefetch_related(), way?

Comment: I don't know what your `G1` or `race` here is (they don't appear in your original code). However, that looks like accessing the `g1` attribute off `race` (whatever it is) is causing the extra query; you'd want `Prefetch('race', queryset=Race.objects.select_related('g1'))` so the prefetch for `race` also includes that race's `g1`...

Comment: I am sorry. Actually I use 6 tables. I should have written not 'G1' but 'photo'... Thank you. I'll try your code with changing 'Race' to 'ItemPhoto', I wrote in the question.